# Как открыть страницу скриптом и выполнить на ней действие

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите, как сделать переход по ссылке чтобы они открылась в новой вкладке и плюс выполнилось какоето действие

Мне нужно запустить этот скрипт из консоли браузера.

1 - Переход по ссылке
2 - Действие Например console.log("Hi!")
3 - Закрыть страницу

Comment: Это не безопасно, представьте как бы это юзали мошенники, такие действия ограничены браузером, и правильно сделали

Answer (score 1):

```js
const newWin = window.open('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/', 'win_name', 'width=200, height=200');
newWin.onload=()=>{
    let div = newWin.document.createElement('div');
    let body = newWin.document.body;
    div.innerHTML = 'Hello!';
    div.style.fontSize = '300px';
    body.insertBefore(div, body.firstChild);
};
```

Читать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods)